# How to get folder name and filename using Files.walk

Tags: java, file

I have a scenario where I need to get the folder name and filename using Files.walk simultaneously.

Below is the directory:
c:\files\foldername1\filename1.txt
c:\files\foldername2\filename2.txt

Following code gives output which are file names

```
c:\\files\foldername1\\filename1.txt
c:\\files\foldername2\\filename2.txt

try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get("c:\\files"))) {
List<String> result = walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
          .map(x -> x.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Following code gives output which is directories

```
c:\\files\foldername1
c:\\files\foldername2

    try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get("c:\\files"))) {

        List<String> result = walk.filter(Files::isDirectory)
                .map(x -> x.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Is there a way to get folder name and file name using one filter at the same time.

Comment: Ditch your filter or filter including both.

Comment: If I don't use the filter my output is something                                                                                    c:\\files\foldername1                                                                                                                      c:\\files\foldername2

Comment: Do you want your walk result to include both folders and regular files?  Or do you want to visit only regular files, and know the folder where each regular file resides?

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Map<Path, List<Path>> files = walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Path::getParent))
```

will give you a `Map` of `List`s to `Path`s. The keys of the map will be the parent directory paths. The values of the map will be lists of all the files which are included in the directory which corresponds to the key of the map entry.